# How to get wkhtmltopdf with a Dockerized Rails App with running ruby:3.0.4-alpine for use with Wicked PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, wkhtmltopdf, alpine-linux, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to upgrade a Dockerized Rails app to Ruby 3+ and Rails 7. Due to other project dependencies, I've landed on this version of Ruby Docker image `ruby:3.0.4-alpine`. Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:3.0.4-alpine

RUN apk --update add --no-cache build-base bash git vim curl postgresql-dev openssl-dev nodejs npm yarn tzdata less \
imagemagick postgresql-client gcompat

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn set version berry

RUN bundle update --bundler
RUN bundle install --jobs 5

ADD . /app

RUN yarn install

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile \
  && RAILS_SECRET_KEY_BASE=secret_key_base RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile apipie:cache \
  && rm -rf node_modules

EXPOSE 5000

VOLUME ["/app/public", "/usr/local/bundle"]

CMD bash -c "bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb"
```

At this point the only dependency in my Rails app that doesn't work with this Dockerfile is `wkhtmltopdf`.

I would prefer to install `wkhtmltopdf` with the Alpine Package Keeper (apk) as part of `RUN apk --update add --no-cache`.

But, it appears that the latest version of Alpine that has the `wkhtmltopdf` package available is [Alpine 3.14](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.15.0). The release notes for Alpine 3.15 state "qt5-qtwebkit, kdewebkit, wkhtmltopdf, and py3-pdfkit have been removed due to known vulnerabilities and lack of upstream support for qtwebkit."

So other than switching off of Alpine Linux, which would present other dependency issues. I would prefer not to do as that seems to be the version used by most Dockerized Rails apps for the foreseeable future, what are my options?

I also tried using the [wkhtmltopdf_binary](https://rubygems.org/gems/wkhtmltopdf_binary/versions/0.12.3.2) gem, but that was last updated in 2016. When I try to export a PDF using [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) with wkhtmltopdf installed by that gem, I get this error:

```
/usr/local/bundle/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf:61:in `<top (required)>': Invalid platform, must be running on Ubuntu
16.04/18.04/20.04 CentOS 6/7/8, Debian 9/10, archlinux amd64, or intel-based Cocoa macOS (missing binary: /usr/local/bundle/gems/wkhtmltopdf-binary-0.12.6.5/bin/wkhtmltopdf_alpine_3.16.0_i386). (RuntimeError) from /usr/local/bundle/bin/wkhtmltopdf:25:in `load' from /usr/local/bundle/bin/wkhtmltopdf:25:in `<main>'
```

I believe I'm getting this error because the docker image ruby:3.0.4-alpine is running Alpine 3.16 and Alpine dropped support for `wkhtmltopdf` on version 3.14. The `wkhtmltopdf_binary` gem hasn't been updated since 2016, so it wouldn't target more recent versions of Alpine.

So, what are my options to work around this? Is there a way to script a compatible installation of the `wkhtmltopdf` in my Dockerfile? If so, how would I do that?

I haven't been able to find another gem that targets more recent versions of Alpine that install wkhtmltopdf. Is there one out there that I'm missing?

This has to be a common problem (Rails app running on Docker Alpine image with Ruby 3+ that needs to export PDFs using wkhtmltopdf).

Or, is there another way to export PDFs in ruby that doesn't depend on wkhtmltopdf that I haven't found? (I've found other NodeJS options, but that introduces a whole other set of dependencies, so a Docker/Ruby solution is preferable.)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and fixed it by adding:

```
FROM surnet/alpine-wkhtmltopdf:3.16.2-0.12.6-full as wkhtmltopdf

RUN apk add --no-cache \
        libstdc++ \
        libx11 \
        libxrender \
        libxext \
        libssl1.1 \
        ca-certificates \
        fontconfig \
        freetype \
        ttf-droid \
        ttf-freefont \
        ttf-liberation
COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf /bin/wkhtmltopdf /bin/libwkhtmltox.so /bin/
```

For more details see https://github.com/Surnet/docker-wkhtmltopdf/pkgs/container/alpine-wkhtmltopdf#other-images

The docker container will then have wkhtmltopdf on the path. We are using the WickedPdf gem in our rails app instead of wkhtmltopdf directly.